# Office js Api error with getCallbackTokenAsync on OutlookWeb

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing a plugin for Outlook for Office 365 and I am using the function `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync`.
When tested on the desktop app (Outlook 2016 Office 365) the function works perfectly, but when the same code is tested online with Outlook web application the callback function is never fired.
There are no errors reported and checking in the Net developer tool I can see the POST request `https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc?action=GetClientAccessToken` is executed correctly and the response contains the correct values, but still my callback function is not fired. 
Here is the code:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({
   isRest: true
}, 
function (result) {
   console.log("Callback is never fired!");
});
```

Is there an error in my code or is it a bug in Office js?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution myself and I'll post it here just in case it might be helpfull to someone.
The problem was that I had an `event.completed()` somewhere else that stopped all requests and relative callbacks. 
Strange though this effetcs only OutlookWeb platform and not Outlook 2016.

Comment: Anything called after event.completed() is not guaranteed to run. Your add-in can be killed at anytime. In Win32 Desktop Outlook, your add-in may hang around, and your function can actually be called again if the user clicks on the button again (for performance improvements of not having to restart your add-in), but your add-in can still be terminated any time after event.completed() so you should not depend on that behavior. In OWA, it is likely you will be terminated right after event.completed()